# How can I install steam on Fedora 28+

Tags: fedora, steam, games

I'm trying to figure out how to install [Steam](https://store.steampowered.com/) on my Fedora 28 laptop. I found [these instructions](https://gist.github.com/mattbell87/137f49baa3b8e2ad497758c9dd84bb19) but it's unclear to me whether I need to use the negativo17 repo to install Steam or if there's some other method.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In versions of Fedora prior to 28 you could use the negativo17 repo but since Fedora 28 the 3rd party repos that are included with Fedora now include one that has Steam packages.

This was mentioned on this Fedora page in the wiki titled: 
[Workstation/Third Party Software Repositories](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Workstation/Third_Party_Software_Repositories), specifically in this section of the page titled: [Restricted Inclusions](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Workstation/Third_Party_Software_Repositories#Restricted_inclusions).

[image: ss1]

To install Steam you simply have to do the following:

```
$ sudo dnf install -y fedora-workstation-repositories
$ sudo dnf install -y steam --enablerepo=rpmfusion-nonfree-steam
```

**NOTE:** The RPMs are in this repo: rpmfusion-nonfree-steam.

For further details on this repo consult the [RPM Fusion Repos page](https://rpmfusion.org/). From here all the repos' links are organized into "Free" and "Nonfree", the Steam RPMs are under the appropriate Fedora version's repo links in the table.